# Handling the requested resource was not found when using an existing resource?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-front-door

My bicep deployment is getting a reference to an existing resource, but in some situations it may not exist.

How can I handle the 'The requested resource was not found' error?

If the resourceis not there, I need to create it with default values. If it is there, I need to do something with the values.

*I know people will tell me it's idempotent, so I will explain further.*
I need to get a reference to an existing front door security policy so I can build a list of associated domains. If that secutiry policy does not exist I need to create it and assosciate it with one domain. If I assume it's idempoent, and create the security policy with one domain it clears out any other domains it already has.

Therefore, I am pulling all the domains and adding my new one to it. Then creating it with this array of domains. This works, except when the security policy doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do all of this within the template. But if you willing to check for the existence of the resource in your script that invokes the deployment and pass in its existence as a parameter, you could leverage the [conditional deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/conditional-resource-deployment#new-or-existing-resource) feature to your advantage here.

The catch is that you will have to pass the value for the parameter in your deployment command (`newOrExisting` in the linked example).